# Arranging taxonomy data in date order

Tags: php, wordpress, post

Hoping you can help me with this query. I've recently been getting into custom post types and managed to create a taxonomy and have them display on the page in the correct format. The way the fields are pulling through at the minute are in order the post is submitted. I need it so the posts rearrange in order of newest, first.

This is the code I'm using:

```
<?php 
    $date = get_field('projectdate');
    $y = substr($date, 0, 4);
    $m = substr($date, 4, 2);
    $d = substr($date, 6, 2);
    $time = strtotime("{$d}-{$m}-{$y}");
    echo date('d/m/Y', $time);
?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

This displays:

22/09/2014  Arts – Musical Parody
08/09/2014  Technology – Graphics – Pop Up Book
08/09/2014  Technology – RM – Spice Rack
08/09/2014  Technology – RM – Bird
08/09/2014  Technology – Graphics – Interior Design
08/09/2014  Technology – Food Technology – Good Life

To be honest I haven't tried anything because I don't know the best solution from here is. If I separated the dates, would the corresponding a tag move with it? Do I need to add PHP around the whole of it? I'm new to PHP so any ideas or tips would be much appreciated. 
Many thanks
Rachael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working.....

```
                                     <?php $args = array( 
                                 'post_type' => 'homework_projects',
                                 'meta_key' => 'projectdate',  
                                 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
                                 'order' => 'ASC', 
                                 'posts_per_page' => $perpage, 
                                 'paged' => $paged, 
                                 'taxonomy' => 'years',
                                 'term' => $term->name
                                 ); 

                                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

                  <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
```

Then referencing the date below:

```
         <?php 
                                        $date = get_field('projectdate');
                                        $y = substr($date, 0, 4);
                                        $m = substr($date, 4, 2);
                                        $d = substr($date, 6, 2);
                                        $time = strtotime("{$d}-{$m}-{$y}");
                                        echo date('d/m/Y', $time);

                                         ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

You can use Order by parameter based on your custom field.

Comment: Hi Arun. Thanks for that link. I've tried a few things but feel I'm getting it wrong because it's a taxonomy. I've tried: <?php $query = new WP_Query( array ( 'post_type' => 'homework_projects', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'meta_key' => 'projectdate', 'order' => 'ASC' ) ); ?>

Comment: ..homework_projects is the CPT but the taxonomy is 'years'. I've tried both with no avail. Can you help? Many thanks

Comment: Also tried <?php $query = new WP_Query( array ( 
          'post_type' => 'homework_projects', 
          'years' => 'projectdate',
          'orderby' => 'date',
           'tax_query' => array(
            array(
             'taxonomy' => 'years'), )
           ) );
          ?>

Comment: try this. $args = array(
 'post_type' => 'homework_projects',
 'tax_query' => array(
   'taxonomy' => 'movie_genre'
 ),
     'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
     'meta_key' => 'projectdate',
     'order' => 'ASC'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

Comment: Thanks for that Arun. I've added this and it doesn't work: <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'homework_projects', 'tax_query' => array( 'taxonomy' => 'movie_genre' ), 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'meta_key' => 'projectdate', 'order' => 'ASC' ); $query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>    so I changed the taxonomy to 'years' and that didn't do it either.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice one thing. I think you are using 'projectdate' field as text field. Use this field as date field. You are using Advanced custom field plugin, so that is very simple.
Make above change and use my code

Comment: I have done this before, below is the code i used there

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'event_start_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => $perpage,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'tax_query' => array(
     array(
      'taxonomy' => 'event_category',
      'field'    => 'term_id',
      'terms'    => $cat_id,
     ),
    ),
   );
   $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

Comment: Hi Arun, thanks so much for your patience. I'm trying this but it's not making a difference:  <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'homework_projects', 
         'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
         'meta_key' => 'event_start_date', 
         'order' => 'ASC', 
         'posts_per_page' => $perpage, 
         'paged' => $paged, 
         'tax_query' => array( array( 
         'taxonomy' => 'years', 
         'field' => 'term_id', 
         'terms' => $cat_id, ), ), ); 
         $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

Comment: Followed by..<?php 
          $date = get_field('projectdate');
          $y = substr($date, 0, 4);
          $m = substr($date, 4, 2);
          $d = substr($date, 6, 2);
          $time = strtotime("{$d}-{$m}-{$y}");
          echo date('d/m/Y', $time);
 
           ?>

Comment: I've tried changing the meta_key to $date but that doesn't do anything either.